# Video recording error in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview, android-mediarecorder

I need to record video file to mp4 formate. But, when I run and click on the record button, it throws error like **FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException** .
Here is my whole code

```
boolean recording = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_final_example);
    initUI();
    initRecorder();
    buttonStopVid.setEnabled(false);
    buttonPlayVid.setEnabled(false);
    buttonStartVid.setOnClickListener(this);

    holder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

protected void initUI(){
    buttonStartVid = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStartRecordVid);
    buttonPlayVid = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlayVid);
    buttonStopVid = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopRecordVid);
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_camera_final);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.buttonStartRecordVid){
        buttonStartVid.setEnabled(false);
        buttonStopVid.setEnabled(true);

        surfaceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        prepareRecorder();
        recording = true;
        recorder.start();

    }
    if(v.getId() == R.id.buttonStopRecordVid){
        buttonPlayVid.setEnabled(true);
        buttonStartVid.setEnabled(true);
        buttonStopVid.setEnabled(false);
        surfaceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        recorder.stop();
        recording = false;
        initRecorder();
        prepareRecorder();
    }
    if(v.getId() == R.id.buttonPlayVid){

    }
}

protected void initRecorder(){
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);

    CamcorderProfile cp = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    recorder.setProfile(cp);

    try{
        File newFile = File.createTempFile("vid", ".mp4", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
        recorder.setOutputFile(newFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void prepareRecorder() {

    recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    prepareRecorder();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if(recording){
        recorder.stop();
        recording = false;
    }
    recorder.release();
}
```

Any ideas of what could be causing this and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: pls add logcat full error in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this link**
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html

it will provide full information that you need.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that your prepareRecorder() function will be called many times which will cause MediaRecorder  throw illegalState exception. MediaRecorder has state machine you need to keep in mind. you need to know which state your MediaRecorder  is and then do the corresponding process. From your exception log, it says that the MediaRecorder  is doing wrong process in wrong state.I think http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html maybe a good doc for you.